# Discrete Plot Custom Color Individual Point Coloring

Tags: plotting, color

How do I individually color each points in the Discrete Plot in order to make it similar like the one that I use in the Legend?

```
R[r_] := 2/(5*3)*1/(2*3)!*((2*r)/(5*3))^(2*3)*E^((-2*r)/(5*3))
SampleInitialConditions = N[Table[R[r], {r, 7, 105, 7}]];
SampleInitialConditionsScientific = 
    SampleInitialConditions /. x_?NumberQ -> ScientificForm[x, 3];
ColorList = {Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red, Brown}, 
       InitialCond]}, {InitialCond, 
            1/Length[SampleInitialConditions], 1, 
      1/Length[SampleInitialConditions]}]} // Flatten;
LabelString = 
  Table[StringForm["\[NumberSign] ``", LS], {LS, 1, 
    Length[SampleInitialConditions]}];
LegendInitialConditions = 
    SwatchLegend[ColorList, LabelString, 
      LegendLabel -> "Initial Conditions", LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
      LegendLayout -> "Row"];
DiscretePlot[
 Callout[SampleInitialConditions[[InitialCond]], 
  StringForm["q[0] & q'[0] = \n ``", 
   SampleInitialConditionsScientific[[InitialCond]]], Above, 
  Background -> LightGray], {InitialCond, 1, 
  Length[SampleInitialConditions]},  
 PlotLabel -> "Table of Sample Initial Conditions", ImageSize -> 900, 
 PlotTheme -> "Web", PlotLegends -> LegendInitialConditions, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorList]
```

The code produces something like this:

[image: Discrete Plot]

How do I match the color of the Legend with point #1 being colored blue and point #15 being colored brown? ColorFunction usually colors the points vertically and not horizontally.

Comment: Crossposted: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2480857

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use "Style" together with "ColorList":

```
DiscretePlot[
 Callout[Style[SampleInitialConditions[[InitialCond]], 
   ColorList[[InitialCond]]], 
  StringForm["q[0] & q'[0] = \n ``", 
   SampleInitialConditionsScientific[[InitialCond]]], Above, 
  Background -> LightGray], {InitialCond, 1, 
  Length[SampleInitialConditions]}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Table of Sample Initial Conditions", ImageSize -> 900, 
 PlotTheme -> "Web", PlotLegends -> LegendInitialConditions, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorList]
```

[image]

Note: I get a message that "InitialCond" can not be used as a part specification. I think this is a bug.